# How do I install MS SQL for ubuntu 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, mssql

I looked up on the internet but all those steps to install were regarding 16.04 version. Is it available yet on 18.04 ? If yes,how?

Comment: I had a look at their repositories, and it looks like for now they only have a couple libraries in the 18.04 repositories. That probably means they are busy working on building packages but are not ready with everything yet.

Comment: When trying to install mssql-server on Ubuntu 18.04 I get error `The following packages have unmet dependencies: mssql-server : Depends: openssl (<= 1.1.0)` so it's not available out-of-the-box. Look at the David Mortals's answer below.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029504/ubuntu-18-04-mssql-repos/1033956#1033956

Answer (score 9):

Microsoft does not provide official mssql-server for 18.04 yet (05-12-2018), for testing only you may try [this](https://github.com/wheelcomplex/mssql-server-ubuntu-18.04) workaround(from me).

> #### Workaround for installing Microsoft's SQL Server (mssql) on Ubuntu
>
> WARNING: FOR TESTING ONLY
>
> 1. Download latest package mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3_amd64.deb from https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017/pool/main/m/mssql-server/
> 2. Change directories
>
>    ```
>    cd ${HOME} && mkdir -p tmp/mssql/newpkg/DEBIAN/ && cd tmp/mssql
>    wget https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/16.04/mssql-server-2017/pool/main/m/mssql-server/mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3_amd64.deb
>    ```
> 3. Unpack
>
>    ```
>    dpkg-deb -x mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3_amd64.deb newpkg/
>    dpkg-deb -e mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3_amd64.deb newpkg/DEBIAN/
>    ```
> 4. Modify
>
>    ```
>    sed -i -e 's#openssl (<= 1.1.0)#openssl (<= 1.1.1)#g' newpkg/DEBIAN/control
>    cat newpkg/DEBIAN/control | grep openssl
>    ```
> 5. Repackage
>
>    ```
>    dpkg-deb -b newpkg/ 18.04-mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3_amd64_.deb
>    ```
> 6. First try, this will fail for dependencies
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg -i 18.04-mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3_amd64_.deb
>    ```
> 7. Install dependencies
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install -f
>    ```
> 8. Second try, this should be done
>
>    ```
>    sudo dpkg -i 18.04-mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3_amd64_.deb
>    ```
> 9. Follow the messages from package to setup the mssql server
>
> **Troubleshooting**
>
> The database directory `/var/opt/mssql` should not put on zfs dataset,
>   if you are using zfs, create a zvol and format as ext4/xfs for it.
>
> Error: "Dump collecting thread [4404] hit exception [6]. Exiting."
>   Fix: `sudo usermod -a -G disk mssql`
>   Reason: mssql user can not access zvol.
>
> References:
>
> - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-linux-2017
> - https://gist.github.com/shamil/3140558

Comment: I also had to change libcurl3 to libcurl4 in the dependencies in step 4 (PHP7 uses V4 and it seems to work with MSSql server).

Answer (score 5):

So, the versions of `ca-certificates` and `openssl` provided by Ubuntu 18.04 actually work fine for `mssql-server`. Presumably it's rejecting `openssh` because 18.04's version of `1.1.0g-2ubuntu4` is technically 'higher' than `mssql-server`'s demanded `<=1.1.0` (and I would think they should have used `<1.1.1` since that still locks you to a `1.1.0` variant while allowing for distribution-specific package versions *which are something you should absolutely expect to run into* but that's neither here nor there.)

## The Fix

1. Install dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libunwind8 libnuma1 libc6 adduser libjemalloc1 libc++1 gdb debconf libcurl3 hostname openssl python libgssapi-krb5-2 libsss-nss-idmap0 gawk sed
   ```

   <sup>(I fully realize you probably have most of these already installed, these are just all of the claimed dependencies.)</sup>
2. Download the package

   ```
   apt-get download mssql-server
   ```
3. Force installation

   ```
   sudo dpkg --force-depends -i mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3.deb
   ```
4. Remove downloaded .deb file

   ```
   rm mssql-server_14.0.3025.34-3_amd64.deb
   ```
  At this point, running any apt command will cause it to (harmlessly) complain that mssql-server has unmet dependencies and instruct you to run:
  `sudo apt --fix-broken install`
  **DO NOT DO THIS. YOU WILL LOSE EVERYTHING YOU JUST DID.**
  If you really want that error to go away, proceed with step 5, otherwise just ignore it and you're done.
5. Convince dpkg that everything is okay

   1. `sudo nano /var/lib/dpkg/status`
       <sup>Your preferred editor is okay too</sup>
   2. Find the entry for mssql-server (for nano it's Ctrl-W, not Ctrl-F)

      Change the depends line from
      `...hostname, openssl (>= 1.0.1), openssl (<= 1.1.0), python (<= 2.7.0)...`
      to
      `...hostname, openssl (>= 1.0.1), openssl (< 1.1.1), python (<= 2.7.0)...`

If you forcibly installed the old versions of `ca-certificates` and `openssl` to get `mssql-server` to install, you can forcibly upgrade them by `apt-get install ca-certificates openssl`. This will remove mssql-server (but your configuration and databases should be left alone). Then you can follow my instructions.

This should avoid you having to deal with the hassle of repackaging things. You *are* trading that for playing tricks on dpkg but doing it this way will probably (I admit this is based on no research) make it easier to upgrade when an official 18.04 package comes out since you avoid creating and using an unofficial package and upgrading to an official package would clean up the changes we made automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft has updated SQL Server 2017 for Linux and now it can be installed in Ubuntu 18.04 but They are recommending for development only.

For more information check out the following Microsoft blog post:
  [Installing SQL Server 2017 for Linux on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SQL-Server/Installing-SQL-Server-2017-for-Linux-on-Ubuntu-18-04-LTS/ba-p/385983)

Answer (score 2):

[Micrsoft's SQL website](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-linux-2017) was last updated in April 2018 and shows Ubuntu 16.04 as the most currently supported version. I would wait until July 26, 2018 when Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS is released to expect support from Microsoft.

Instead of paying for Microsoft's SQL you could try the [free version of MySQL](https://mysqlrelease.com/2018/04/mysql-support-for-ubuntu-18-04-and-fedora-28/) which supports Ubuntu 18.04 already.

Comment: MySQL and other open source databases are already included in the Ubuntu repositories, so no need to get them elsewhere, unless you need a specific version.

Comment: @JanC I was highlighting the Manfacturer's website for information about MySQL availability for 18.04. Thanks for installation tip that benefit everyone.

Comment: If MSSQL is what you need because other software you use depends on it, installing MySQL isn't going to do you any good.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu 18.10 you'll need to revise David Mortals answer slightly by adding the following to step 4:

```
sed -i -e 's#libjemalloc1#libjemalloc2#g' newpkg/DEBIAN/control
```

This is assuming that `libjemalloc2` is backward compatible with `libjemalloc1` and so far on my dev machine it seems to be working fine.