# How to uninstall Ubuntu 18.04 and go back to 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, 18.04

I want to go back Ubuntu 16.04, because a lot of packages are not supported yet in 18.04. For example, MSSQLServer.

Comment: 1. First of all you should **backup** your current system or at least all the files that you cannot afford to lose; 2. There is no rollback (unless you have a backup of the complete 16.04 LTS system). But it is simple: Make a fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. You can keep the `/home` as a separate **home** partition and at the partitioning window of the installer select **Something else** and select that partition (as well as a root partition and a swap partition).

Comment: Or don't:  install virtualbox, 16.04 in vbox and use msssql from there. And wait for microsoft to add support for 18.04

Comment: Or see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1032532/how-do-i-install-ms-sql-for-ubuntu-18-04-lts

Comment: comment 1 has right idea but one doesn't need to have a separate /home partition to save previous. Not really suitable for comment though pretty simple. To give basic idea, - on a 16.04 live session mount the current 18.04 volume. As root then delete all folders but /home. Then unmount, go to installer > something else, remove current 18.04 partition, install 16.04 (as just /) to that exact space/size 18.04 was in using same user name & **do not format**. That will install 16.04, will not touch /home & when you log in it'll be to same home directory you had.