# How to install mssql-server in Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: 19.04, mssql

While following [this tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-2017) when executing

```
sudo apt-get install -y mssql-server
```

I get in the output the next error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-server : Depends: libjemalloc1 but it is not installable
                Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
```

what should I do?

Comment: Note that `mssql-server` is technically 'not supported' by Microsoft for 19.04 - they had designed it for 18.04 LTS and LTS releases.  Your mileage with it working properly will vary.

Comment: Dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092417/mssql-server-depends-on-libjemalloc1-which-is-a-virtual-package-and-is-not-prov – same solutions work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I based my answer on [this one for 18.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1092417/mssql-server-depends-on-libjemalloc1-which-is-a-virtual-package-and-is-not-prov). Install these packages:

[libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u11_amd64.deb](http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/o/openssl/libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u12_amd64.deb) and
[libjemalloc1_3.6.0-11_amd64.deb](http://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jemalloc/libjemalloc1_3.6.0-11_amd64.deb)

with the commands:

```
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.0.0_1.0.1t-1+deb8u11_amd64.deb    
sudo dpkg -i libjemalloc1_3.6.0-11_amd64.deb
```

Comment: But is MSSQL for Linux safe to use when it depends on the old `libssl1.0.0`?
Especially if you want connections from client to be encrypted?

Comment: This was working for me but stopped abruptly after the last server reboot and I can't get it working even on a new install of 19.04. I just get `A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)`. I'm guessing some packages were updated that broke compatibility. Are there any workarounds for this?

Comment: @MrCalvin this is the price to install the MSSQL in new versions of Linux. MS need to upgrade the MSSQL.

Comment: Yea, it surprise me. I assume they have used hundreds (perhaps thousands) of hours to port to Linux, and then they won't use a few hours to keep it up-to-date. In a way it put the hundreds(or thousands) of hours to waste. In my view and in practice you can't use MS-SQL on Linux in production. What a waste!