# How to install mssql server in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, microsoft, mssql

Please How do I Install SQL server in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Microsoft does not yet fully support 22.04. You have two options: use a Docker container for SQL Server on Linux or downgrade to 20.04 (which is still an excellent release).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install mssql-server in Ubuntu 19.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147280/how-to-install-mssql-server-in-ubuntu-19-04)

Answer (score 0):

[Install MS SQL Server on Ubuntu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=ubuntu2204)

You have to click on the tab for Ubuntu 22.04 and also make sure which pieces you copy and paste as others are specific to 22.04
Worked great for me.

I had to modify one command from:

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U sa -P '<YourPassword>'
```

to add a `-C`

```
sqlcmd -C -S localhost -U sa -P '<YourPassword>'
```